# Ruby Rails 2.3.x What is the theory behind pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table with 3000 user records. Pagination works fine, but when looking at the firebug timeline, it states the content size of the download is 2.37MB with 9.62s time to download. Pagination works fine, but I was hoping it only downloaded just the first 25 records and provided links to the additional available pages. I have tried sunspot, thinking-sphinxs, the rails find_in_batches, a straight up :limit => 25, etc.

If pagination splits up the recordset and displays 25 records per page, then why does it *appear* to still download the entire table? Does not this defeat the theory behind pagination or what am I missing?

```
@users = User.all(:conditions => ["client_id = ?", current_user.client_id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
```

Obviously, the goal here is to load my page within a second or two, as apposed to 10 or 12 seconds. Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the gem you use for pagination, but if it's any of the usual suspects (or still built into Rails 2.3 - I don't recall), it should in fact use a `LIMIT` to query only the relevant records. Your slow page load time is most likely due to something else. Take a look at your development log to see the actual query.

Comment: Holy heavens you are right. I looked at my log file and I had MUCH more sql activity going on than I was aware of, due to the fact I have so many options and features on the page at the same time. Now I know where to start refactoring. I wasn't seeing it untill you mentioned it, so I had to add config.log_level = :debug to my .rb log file then the light was turned on. Needless now to say, I am using will_paginate. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. If you have a lot of SQL queries for every page load, you might have a 1+N problem here or there. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Problem solved. The massive load of content that was being downloaded was not in fact stemming from the sql call I thought to be the culprit. It was in fact other sql calls I was making that was being loaded into a hidden div. But this discovery was made by means of being pointed in the directions you mentioned, so thanks again.